# Как поменять цвет выделения элемента в ListBox в фокусе и без?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ListBox со списком элементов типа string. Выбрал элемент, он выделился серым цветом, все прекрасно. Затем, если ListBox неактивен (без фокуса), то соответственно цвет выделения элемента становится совсем блеклым, и глаза напрягаются для определения выделенного элемента в ListBox. А мне как раз надо чтобы цвет выделения элемента в ListBox не менялся не зависимо от фокуса.

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = listBox1.Resources;

//Устанавливаем цвет выделения активного ListBox'а
res.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));

//Устанавливаем цвет выделения неактивного ListBox'а
res.Add(SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
```

Comment: Это работает на NET Framework 4.5. Как такое сделать на версии 4.0?

Comment: Делайте правильно — переопределите шаблон. Понятно что хак наподобие описанного может сработать, а может и не сработать.

Можно подсмотреть шаблон Expression Blend'ом, или на крайняк [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).